# Uzbek cuisine - Cookbook in English?

Tags: cookbook

Is there a book on Uzbek cooking in English? I found one in Russian, but English would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Martin and welcome to Seasoned Advice! Here is a link to an  [online cookbook](http://www.uzbekcuisine.com) . A book, The Art of UZBEK cooking by Lynn Visson is available on Amazon. If you perform a Google search there are many available sources.